# Using Regex to replace part of Array name DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex, string

I have an array and i'd like to replace the name in DOM with a regex.
For exemple :

```
name=myArray[0]ok
name=myArray[120]sfq
name=myArray[23]dlzoifd
```

And i'd like to replace 0, 120 or 23 by the numbre i want to have :

```
name=myArray[0]ok
name=myArray[1]sfq
name=myArray[2]dlzoifd
```

Does someone have an idea for replacing with regex ?
Thanks !

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

**Do you want like following this:**  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aX5kY8/2)

```
$re = "/([^\\[]+\\[)(\\d)\\d*(\\].*)/m"; 
$str = "name=myArray[0]ok\nname=myArray[120]sfq\nname=myArray[23]dlzoifd"; 
$subst = "$1$2$3"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```